# Cómo puedo hacer para presionar multiples enlaces al mismo tiempo

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy buscando ayuda para este "problema" que tengo.
Estoy queriendo descargar todas las fotos y videos que tengo en mi Snapchat y para eso pedí una solicitud para que me permitan descargar todo en la computadora. Entonces, me dieron un documento HTML donde están todos los enlaces para descargar los datos uno por uno. El problema es que entre fotos y videos tengo más de 2.000.
Lo que se me ocurrio es modificar el HTML para que se me presionen todos los enlaces de "download" a la vez, o algo parecido, y así no tener que presionar el botón "download" por cada archivo que descague.
Alguna idea?. Los leo. Gracias de antemano

**PD: Acá les dejo un fragmento del HTML para que se den una idea.**

````
  <h1>Memories</h1>
  <p>This section includes information about Memories you've saved in Snapchat. Download links below will expire 7 days from when your data file was made available to you.</p>
  <p class="important">
    <script>
      function downloadMemories(url) {
        var parts = url.split("?");
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("POST", parts[0], true);
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            var a = document.createElement("a");
            a.href = xhttp.responseText;
            a.style.display = "none";
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
            document.getElementById("mem-info-bar").innerText = "";
          } else if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status >= 400) {
            document.getElementById("mem-info-bar").innerText = "Oops!                 Something went wrong. Status " + xhttp.status
          }
        };
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhttp.send(parts[2]);
      }
    </script>
    <div id='mem-info-bar' style='color:red'></div>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th style="white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;"><b>Date</b></th>
          <th style="white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;"><b>Media Type</b></th>
          <th style="white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;"><b> </b></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2021-07-24 19:03:03 UTC</td>
          <td>VIDEO</td>
          <td><a href="javascript:downloadMemories('https://app.snapchat.com/dmd/memories-1');">download</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2021-07-24 19:01:49 UTC</td>
          <td>VIDEO</td>
          <td><a href="javascript:downloadMemories('https://app.snapchat.com/dmd/memories-2);">download</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2021-07-24 19:00:54 UTC</td>
          <td>VIDEO</td>
          <td><a href="javascript:downloadMemories('https://app.snapchat.com/dmd/memories-3);">download</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2021-03-27 05:13:06 UTC</td>
          <td>VIDEO</td>
          <td><a href="javascript:downloadMemories('https://app.snapchat.com/dmd/memories-4);">download</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2021-03-11 00:00:10 UTC</td>
          <td>VIDEO</td>
          <td><a href="javascript:downloadMemories('https://app.snapchat.com/dmd/memories-5);">download</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2021-03-10 23:58:39 UTC</td>
          <td>VIDEO</td>
          <td><a href="javascript:downloadMemories('https://app.snapchat.com/dmd/memories-6);">download</a></td>
        </tr>```


  CAPTURA DE PANTALLA: https://i.stack.imgur.com/egJp0.png
````

Comment: No entiendo que hace la función `downloadMemories(url)` , por lo que veo crea un enlace al archivo de descarga y luego le da clic para iniciar la descarga. Podrías añadir un Javascript que capture todos los link y luego ejecutas en un ciclo `for` la función del `href`. Ahora sí lo único que cambia es el número del archivo haces un `for` hasta el número del último archivo y vas llamando a la función.